# Cocoa: bind to composite object and observe child properties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

Is it possible to bind to a custom object and get notified when specific properties of that object change?

Example:

Each sales rep object has a reference to a sales statistics object with stats for car and truck sales. A custom `NSView` is used to draw both, car and truck sales in one graphic.

The custom view needs access to the full statistics object, so I bound it to `salesRep.salesStats`.

However, when I change the `carSales` property I need a way for the view to update. Currently it doesn't update, because it is bound to the parent object.

I'd like to avoid establishing bindings for each sales type (this is only an example, my specific case is more complex).

```
@interface SBSalesRep : NSObject {

@property (strong) SBSalesStatistics *salesStats;
}

@interface SBSalesStatistics : NSObject
{
@property (assign) NSInteger carSales;
@property (assing) NSInteger truckSales;
}

@interface SBProgressView : NSView
{
@property (strong) SBSalesStatistics *statsToDisplay;
}

// Setup
SBSalesRep *salesRep = [SBSalesRep new];

// Bind to stats object, because we need car and tuck sales:
[progressView bind:@"statsToDisplay" 
          toObject:salesRep 
       withKeyPath:@"salesStats"  // How to get notified of property changes here?
           options:nil];

// This needs to trigger an update in the statistics view
salesRep.salesStats.carSales = 50;

// I tried this, but it does not work:
[salesRep willChangeValueForKey:@"salesStatistics"];
salesRep.salesStats.carSales = 50;
[salesRep didChangeValueForKey:@"salesStatistics"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

```
// I tried this, but it does not work:
[salesRep willChangeValueForKey:@"salesStatistics"];
salesRep.salesStats.carSales = 50;
[salesRep didChangeValueForKey:@"salesStatistics"];
```

My guess would be that this doesn't work because the key you're notifying for is `salesStatistics` but the key you're binding to is `salesStats`. If those keys were the same, I would expect this approach to work.

Beyond that, a better approach might be to add dependencies like this:

```
@implementation SBSalesRep

+ (NSSet *) keyPathsForValuesAffectingSalesStats
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects: @"salesStats.carSales", @"salesStats.truckSales", nil];
}

@end
```

This will cause any observation (binding or otherwise) of the key `salesStats` to also implicitly observe `salesStats.carSales` and `salesStats.truckSales`, and should achieve the desired effect without having to notify manually with `-will/didChangeValueForKey:`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using a key path was the part that I was missing.